# Selecting datetime data in python

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I'm running into issues selecting data at certain datetimes in my dataset.
Basically I have one dataset with hourly data, and a dataset with observations (also hourly data). In the observation dataset, however, some data is missing. I want to remove the datapoints in the simulated dataset from the dataset, so that I can compare the simulations to observations.

I've tried something like this:

```
CO2_tt=[]

for j in timers:

     if j in date:

        CO2_tt.append(CO2_t[i])

print(shape(CO2_tt))
```

In this timers is the datetime list of my simulations and date is the list of observation timedates.

This doesn't seem to work. I get a CO2_tt with a shape of (514,), which means it cut 70 datapoints, but now all data has the same value.

If someone could help me I would really appreciate it!

Comment: ok.. what is `timers` and `date`? or let me ask this, could you give us snippet of your respective datasets? the hourly data one and the simulated one ?

Comment: From the very limited info you give, it seems that you append your complete CO_t dataset to your CO_tt dataset many times. That's probably not what you intended, but may well explain the shape if your test for j in date always returns True..

Comment: To keep it simple just include example of your input and desired output.

Comment: input would be two list of datetimes.datetimes with corresponding list of floats. Like this: 2014-10-06 17:00:00 | 423.1670089 and 2014-10-06 19:00:00 | 417.498. So the longest list should be the same length as the shortest list with the correct corresponding values.

Comment: I see that you're appending to `CO2_tt` an element at index `i` from `CO2_t`. If the index never changes, that may explain why all data has the same value.

Comment: So how do I loop through i? I can't get it to work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, the elements in `CO2_t` correspond to the elements in `timers`, then you just [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) your `timers` list and where there is an element in `date`, you append the element at the enumerated index of `CO2_t` to `CO2_tt`.

```
CO2_tt = []
for i, j in enumerate(timers):
    if j in date:
        CO2_tt.append(CO2_t[i])
```